# Can't access JSON attributes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, reactjs

I've been battling with this seemingly simple issue for a good two hours now.. Please educate me. I just don't undestand what I'm doing wrong.

I have a PHP script that I call from a react component with a $.get function like so:

```
this.serverRequest = $.get("php/get_house.php", {"id":this.props.houseId}, function(data){
    this.setState({house: data, loading: false});
}.bind(this));
```

I then pass the data in this.state.house into another component :

```
<ShowHouse house={this.state.house} />
```

In ShowHouse component I log the data:

```
console.log(this.props.house);
console.log(this.props.house[0]);
```

The first one returns something that chrome console shows as [{...}], with the data in 0:nth position, the second one returns what you'd expect - just the data in normal JSON format like in the block below.

My JSON that I get printed on the page if I simply open the PHP-script with an id, like ..php?id=1

```
[{"heading":"Kuin uusi","id":"1","city":"Helsinki"}]
```

How do I access this data? I get an error "Cannot read property 'heading' of undefined" if I simply try to access it by

```
console.log(this.props.house[0].heading).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array syntax

```
this.props.house[0]["heading"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I never figured to try that syntax before. Altough didn't solve my problem hehe.